# How to get Data Extension ID using Journey ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, dataextensions, rest

In Salesforce marketing cloud, I need to get the Data Extension ID of a journey using REST or SOAP API Call. Then this Data Extension ID will be used in further set of API calls. The challenge was to get the Data Extension ID of a given journey in Journey Builder.

I found below link of Marketing cloud REST API documentation, but seems it does not return the Data Extension ID with the journey information.

[GET /interaction/v1/interactions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionCollection.htm)

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding extras=all as a query param in your Rest call.  I do not remember if that contains the necessary data which is the Journey's event definition.

It is configured with the entry event for the Journey.

You will need to use interaction/v1/eventDefinitions to get the Journey's entry event. Two separate Rest calls -- one to get the Journey then another to get its entry event definition which contains the Data Extension information.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your Data Extension's ID using **one call** (instead of two) to `/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/` endpoint.

You'll need to filter by your Journey's name by adding it to the query's url:

```
{{rest_endpoint}}/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/?name=YOUR_JOURNEYS_NAME
```

The result will contain your data extension's ID in addition to other information like the `eventDefinitionId`, `eventDefinitionKey` and `dataExtensionName`..