# Retrieve all Data Extensions across all running journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

I found out on this forum there is an option with Marketing Cloud API to retrieve all the Data Extensions associated with Journeys.

When using Postman, the request below works perfectly

```
GET /interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/
Host: xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer xxx
```

It returns an object that I can query without issues.

However, when trying to run the same script as part of a SSJS Activity in Automation Studio, it just fails.

```
    <script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1");

        var authEndpoint = 'https://xxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com';
        var payload = {
            clientId: "xxx",
            clientSecret: "xxx"
        };
        var authurl = authEndpoint + '/v1/requestToken';  
        var contentType = 'application/json';   

        var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(authurl, contentType, Stringify(payload));
        
        if(accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
            var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
            var accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
            var auth = "Bearer " + accessToken;

        }
    
    }

    /* Get the Journeys details */
    
    try {
        
        var deEndpoint  = "https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/";
        
        var HeaderNames = ["Authorization"];
        var HeaderValues = [Auth]

        var deRequest       = HTTP.Get(deEndpoint, HeaderNames, HeaderValues);
        var requestResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(deRequest.Response[0]);

        Write("Object: "+ requestResponse);
        
    } catch (err) {
        Write(Stringify(err));
    }
    </script>
```

After executing the Activity, it returns **Object: null**

I couldn't find any information in the documentation about this API though:
GET /interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/, only from comments on this forum.

[How to get Data Extension ID using Journey ID](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248175/how-to-get-data-extension-id-using-journey-id)

Is there an alternative way to run the same request? Thank you

Comment: What is the value of the variable deRequest? also take into account that auth variable is lowercase when you retrieve the token and you wrote "var HeaderValues = [Auth]" with uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code will return all the journeys. I will share the code to fetch DE names later. Please refer to the documentation link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/getInteractionCollection.html

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");

    var payload = '{"grant_type":"client_credentials",';
            payload += '"client_id":"xxxx",';
            payload += '"client_secret":"xxxx",';
            payload += '"account_id":"xxxx"}';
      var OAuth2URL = "https://xxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
      var contentType = 'application/json';
      var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(OAuth2URL, contentType, payload);
      var tokenObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult["Response"][0]);
      var accessToken = tokenObj.access_token;
      var auth = "Bearer " + accessToken;

/* Get the Journeys details */

try {
    
    var deEndpoint  = "https://xxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions";
  
  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(deEndpoint);
      req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
      req.retries = 2;
      req.continueOnError = true;
      req.contentType = "application/json";
 req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
      req.method = "GET";
      var resp = req.send();
 var resultString = String(resp.content);
 var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
 Write(resultString);
    
} catch (err) {
    Write(Stringify(err));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Dennon - You are right, I saw this API in the Documentation, but when I was looking at the response, I couldn't find the associated Data Extension. If you have the code to fetch the DE name, that would be fantastic! Cheers

Comment: Happy to know that the code worked for you. Thanks for the vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dennon - Actually, I have changed the API with ***/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions*** and your code works like a charm!!!

Might be useful for other developers

```
try {
                
    var apiURL      = "https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions";
    var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(apiURL);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json";
    req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
    req.method = "GET";
    var resp = req.send();
    var resultString = String(resp.content);
    var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));
    Write(resultString);
                    
    
} catch (apiError) {
    
    Write(Stringify(apiError));
}
```

Comment: Please mark Dennon's answer as solving your issue, resp. upvote it, instead of praising it in another answer.